# How can I fix 'You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block' error in Django signals?

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I'm using Django 4.1.3
in my signals.py, for an object, I want to do these things:

1. Create an object of CLASS1
2. Create an objects of CLASS2
3. Call a function for sending a message

and this is my code:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Event)
def is_confirmed_changed(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.id is None:
        pass
    else:
        e = Event.objects.get(id=instance.id)
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                CLASS1.objects.create(
                    user=instance.creator,
                )
        except:
            pass
        send_text_message()
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                CLASS2.objects.create(
                    event=e,
                )
        except:
            pass
```

on my localhost everything looks fine but when I test it on my server i get this error:
[You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6WcC.png)

I tried adding "with transaction.atomic()" or changing the order of my steps but i failed anyway.